# Change an existing Dataset name in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I created a report using the wizard in SSRS (VS 2008). I wasnt asked to name my dataset and by default it names my dataset as "DataSet1" is it possible to change my dataset name?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `Name` value in `Dataset Properties`:

[image]

Comment: How do I access DataSet properties? I tried looking for dataset properties but if you create a report through wizard, the dataset does not show in Solution Explorer. Am I missing something here?